# Geometric interpretations theorems about rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, contest-math

Consider the following theorems about rank:

1. If $A$ is a $k \times m$-matrix, $B$ a $m \times n$ matrix and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=m$, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$
2. $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)-m$

I know that the "geometric" interpretation of a matrix is that it's a linear map from one vectorspace to another vectorspace and that the rank is by definition the amount of vectors in the basis of the image of the linear map=dimension column space of the matrix that belongs to that linear map.

Does someone know if there exists a geometric intepretation for these theorems? I am familiar with the proofs of both of them. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. immediately follows from 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these theorems concern the result of applying $A$ to the range (i.e. the set of outputs) of $B$.

> If A is a $k \times m$ matrix, $B$ $m \times n$, and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=m$, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$

For a set $S \subset \Bbb R^m$, let $A(S) \subset \Bbb R^k$ denote the set $A(S) = \{Ax : x \in S\}$. In particular, note that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \dim(A(\Bbb R^m))$.

The key here is to understand that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = m$ means that $A$ is an embedding of $\Bbb R^m$ into $\Bbb R^k$. More specifically, it maps the canonical vectors ("axis directions") of $\Bbb R^k$ to the (linearly independent) columns of $A$. Thus, for any subspace $U$ of $\Bbb R^m$, $\dim(A(U)) = \dim(U)$. Thus, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \dim AB(\Bbb R^n) = \dim A(B(\Bbb R^n)) = \dim(B(\Bbb R^n)) = \operatorname{rank}(B).
$$

> $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) - m$

Here, it's useful to have a geometric understanding of the kernel (AKA nullspace) of a linear transformation. The kernel of $A$ (denoted by $\ker(A)$) consists of all vectors that are mapped (or if you prefer, "squished") to the zero $0$.  The *rank nullity theorem* tells us that when $A$ has input space $\Bbb R^m$ (i.e. has $m$ columns), we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A) + \dim \ker (A) = m.
$$
In other words, the dimension of the input space is "conserved" in some sense. If the outputs of $A$ span a $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq m$-dimensional subspace, then there must have been $m - \operatorname{rank}(A)$ "dimensions of space" that were mapped to zero.

With that established, we can now interpret the inequality as follows: we can rearrange the inequality to get
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq \operatorname{rank}(B) - (m - \operatorname{rank}(A)) = \operatorname{rank}(B) - \dim \ker(A).
$$
In other words: the greatest amount by which multiplication with $A$ can reduce the rank of $B$ is $\dim \ker(A)$.

---

We can leverage our understanding into a proof if we apply the reasoning behind the rank-nullity theorem and considering what $A$ does to the outputs of $B$.  Let $A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}$ denote the linear map whereby $A$ is only applied to the range of $B$.  Noting that
$$
A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}(B(\Bbb R^n)) = A(B(\Bbb R^n)) = (AB)(\Bbb R^n),
$$
we see that $\operatorname{rank}(A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) = \operatorname{rank}(AB)$. By the rank nullity theorem, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) + \dim \ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) =\\
\operatorname{rank}(A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) + \dim \ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) =
 \\ \dim B(\Bbb R^n) = \operatorname{rank}(B).
$$
Now, we want to find an upper bound for $\dim \ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)})$. By definition, $\ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)})$ consists of the vectors that are in the range of $B$ that are also mapped to $0$. In other words, it is the intersection of the spaces $B(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\ker(A)$.  With that, we can see that $\ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) \subset \ker(A)$, so that
$$
\dim \ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) \leq \dim \ker (A) = m - \operatorname{rank}(A).
$$
Putting all this together, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(B) = 
\operatorname{rank}(AB) + \dim \ker (A|_{B(\Bbb R^n)}) 
\\ \leq \operatorname{rank}(AB) + \dim \ker (A)
\\ = \operatorname{rank}(AB) + m - \operatorname{rank}(A).
$$
Rearranging the inequality $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(AB) + m - \operatorname{rank}(A)$ yields the desired result.

Comment: Hi, can you from rank-nullity thm conclude that rank(B)=n? Since A*B is a k x n matrix, so that: Rk(AB)+Nul(AB)=n right?

Comment: You can conclude that the rank of $B$ is **at most** $n$, but there is no reason to believe that it is exactly $n$.

Comment: Yes indeed, alright thanks a lot